# Decide on a Controller based on Subdomain

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a multitenant application written in dot6 in which each Tenant gets its own Controller with the same Actions + extra actions specific for the tenant.

Controller Look like this where in basecontroller the default methods are specified:

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "testTenantJwt")]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Area("testTenantOne")]
[Route(Routes.Base)]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v2.0")]
public class TestTenantOneController : BaseController
{
  public TestTenantOneController() : base()
  {
  }

[HttpPost(Routes.Record.RecordState)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(E2PResult))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, Type = typeof(E2PResult))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, Type = typeof(E2PResult))]
public async Task<IActionResult> TestMethod([FromBody] RecordStateRequest request)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

}

And the Route object where the routes are stored looks like this

```
public static partial class Routes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the base route for all routes.
    /// </summary>
    public const string Base = "api/";
}

public partial class Routes
{
  public class Record
  {
    public const string Base = "record/";
    public const string Create = Base + "create";
    public const string Process = Base + "process/{recordId}";
    public const string RecordState = Base + "state";
  }
}
```

I also use the basic UseEndpoints:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
```

And now every tenant should only can access its own Controller and use the specified Authorization method.
For example if I come from the url testTenantOne.domain.com i should land in the TestTenantOne Controller and get Authorized by the testTenantJwt schema. But i noticed in the default routing it just takes the Controller action which matches the authentication + route the best, which is not working for me cause multiple Tenants are using ApiKey authentication. I also had a look at filters but as far as i understand they are too late in the pipeline so that a controller action was already choosen.
How can I filter out the other controllers and only use the one matching the one where the subdomain matches the area attribute of the controller for example.

Comment: I think this approach explains your best how to handle multitenant architecture https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-building-a-multi-tenant-applications-with-asp-net-core/

Comment: @DA thx for the link but the library the are refering to is not updated in 7 years and i the website is for sale :D

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't understand your question well. As far as I know, the routing middleware should be executed [before the the authentication middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#middleware-order), so that whenever we set the correct routing rule inside our project, it should help us to direct our url to the correct controller/action then execute the correct authentication scheme. Then about the [Area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-7.0#areas-for-controllers-with-views)

Comment: I'm afraid you might miss some important configuration to make the routing work? Pls correct me if I misunderstood your issue.